# Create component & add it to a specific module with Angular-CLI

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm starting to use angular-cli and I've already read a lot to find an answer about what I want to do...no success, so I came here.

Is there a way to create a component to a new module?

e.g.: `ng g module newModule`

`ng g component newComponent` (how to add this component to newModule??)

because the angular-cli default behavior is to put all new components inside `app.module`. I would like to choose where my component will be, so that I can create separated modules and won't have all my components inside `app.module` . It is possible to do that using angular-cli or do I have to do this manually?

Answer (score 359, accepted):

To create a component as part of a module you should

1. `ng g module newModule` to generate a module,
2. `cd newModule` to change directory into the `newModule` folder
3. `ng g component newComponent` to create a component as a child of the module.

UPDATE: Angular 9

Now it doesn't matter what folder you are in when generating the component.

1. `ng g module NewModule` to generate a module.
2. `ng g component new-module/new-component` to create NewComponent.

Note: When the Angular CLI sees new-module/new-component, it understands and translates the case to match `new-module -> NewModule` and `new-component -> NewComponent`. It can get confusing in the beginning, so easy way is to match the names in #2 with the folder names for the module and component.

Comment: You can also stay in the project root and prefix the component with the module name `ng g component moduleName/componentName`.

Comment: With Angular CLI version 1.6.8, I was always getting error sying that 'specified module doesn't exists', when I sepcify an existing module. It worked when I tried the following command:  *ng generate service service1 --module=module1/module1.module.ts*. Note: my service name is *service1* and my module name is *module1*

Comment: @JayChase's answer is the better option

Comment: @Alexander, though files are being generate its module entry is not working for me, I mean command is not registering component in module.ts, can you help me  with this?

Comment: If you're getting this error: `Could not find an NgModule. Use the skip-import option to skip importing in NgModule.` do step 2 above.  I had to cd into the src/app dir.

Comment: This would create a new component in the specified directory but wouldn't register it in the module. It will register it in the app.module. you would need to specify the module with the `--module` option like: `ng g component <your component> --module=<your module name>`

Comment: outdated as of 6th Oct, Angular 6

Comment: Outdated. Angular 6 does not depend on folder structures to see which module the component is in. Two modules can be in the same directory. @daniel's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44812014/511719 works for Angular 6.

Comment: This answer works updates the current folder  module with component info. If you use the below command from root folder `ng g component moduleName/componentName` then the app module is updated.

Comment: you can  add a module into a specific component doing `ng g module  pages/pages-module --flat` or add a module for router into a specific component folder `ng g module members/member-routing --flat`

Answer (score 260):

```
ng g component nameComponent --module=app.module.ts
```

In Angular 14:

```
ng g component nameComponent --module=app --dry-run
```

Comment: the other answers work, but this is the most efficient. Its worth adding `--dry-run` to the end of that just to see what will be affected, it's a nice sanity check

Comment: `ng g component path/to/myComponent --module=app.module.ts --dry-run` is a very useful command; just to make sure your component is created in the correct directory.

Comment: You can use a relative path in the module option, as follows `ng g component componentName --module=../../sibling/path/custom.module.ts --dry-run`

Comment: `ng g c newComponent --module app` works as well. I used this in the terminal while not in the same directory as the app.module.ts file and it put it in the correct module

Answer (score 82):

Not sure if maybe Alexander Ciesielski's answer was correct at the time of writing, but I can verify that this no longer works. It doesn't matter which directory in the project you run the Angular CLI. If you type

```
ng g component newComponent
```

it will generate a component and import it into the app.module.ts file

The only way you can use CLI to automatically import it into another module is by specifying

```
ng g component moduleName/newComponent
```

where moduleName is a module you've already defined in your project. If the moduleName doesn't exist, it'll put the component in moduleName/newComponent directory but still import it into app.module

Comment: it was the right answer for me at the time..it works properly. I create a pull request to add this information to the docs. One of it's contributors ask me to remove cd-ing part..in the end will be 1. `ng g module newModule`  2. `ng g component new-module/newComponent` according to him should be new-module instead of newModule

Comment: Just to point out, using technique by Alexander Ciesielski and works as expected. I should note, I did not need to create component simply needed to create folder. So I just `mkdir` a folder, and then ran n g component newComponent inside of newly created folder.

Comment: I would say that full answer is `ng g component moduleName/newComponent -m moduleName`

Comment: In my case the component name is same as the module name so I created the module with `ng generate module {modComName}` 1) Created the folder 2) Created a module file inside the folder of same name ; the command `ng generate component {modComName}` actually 1) Created a component file inside the folder of same name 2) Modified the module to import the component

Comment: Be careful if you create a module and import it into a base module; `ng` adds imports to the *end* of the array; but you may want  : ["The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by design."](https://angular.io/guide/router#module-import-order-matters)

Answer (score 56):

I didn't find an answer that showed how to use the cli to generate a component inside a top level module folder, and also have the component automatically added the the module's declaration collection.

To create the module run this:

```
ng g module foo
```

To create the component inside the foo module folder and have it added to the foo.module.ts's declaration collection run this:

```
ng g component foo/fooList --module=foo.module.ts
```

And the cli will scaffold out the module and component like this:

[image]

--EDIT the new version of the angular cli behaves differently.  1.5.5 doesn't want a module file name so the command with v1.5.5 should be

```
ng g component foo/fooList --module=foo
```

Comment: Yay for the `--module` argument; the [docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-module) say "Allows specification of the declaring module." ; I would add `--module` specifies which *existing* module should be *modified* to import the module you are *about to create*

Comment: @TheRedPea  I believe you meant to say " --module specifies which existing module should be modified to import the component you are ..."

Comment: Yep you're right!  Existing module modified with reference to new *component*

Answer (score 18):

You can try below command, which describes the,

```
ng -> Angular 
g  -> Generate
c  -> Component
-m -> Module
```

Then your command will be like:

```
ng g c user/userComponent -m user.module
```

Comment: this works for angular 12, there's no need for `.ts` after `.module` so this is perfect. and as tony mentioned, It's worth adding `--dry-run` to the end of that just to see what will be affected, it's a nice sanity check

Answer (score 14):

For Angular v4 and Above, simply use:

```
ng g c componentName -m ModuleName
```

Comment: Throws an error `Specified module does not exist` whereas module existed

Comment: You don't specify the name of the module, you specify the module's filename.

Comment: Works like charm! e.g. if your module file is `user-settings.module.ts` and you want to add a component `public-info` then the command will be: `ng g c PublicInfo -m user-settings`

Comment: This is the simplest and cleanest answer!

Answer (score 11):

this is what worked for me :

```
1 -->  ng g module new-module

2 -->  ng g c new-module/component-test --module=new-module/new-module.module.ts
```

If you want to generate a component without its directory use `--flat`  flag.

Comment: don't need to write .ts

Comment: --module=path-to-module worked form me thanks @Mohamed Makkaoui

Answer (score 10):

1. First, you generate a module by executing.

```
ng g m modules/media
```

this will generate a module called `media` inside `modules` folder.

2. Second, you generate a component added to this module

```
ng g c modules/media/picPick --module=modules/media/media.module.ts
```

the first part of the command `ng g c modules/media/picPick` will generate a component folder called `picPick` inside `modules/media` folder witch contain our new `media` module.

the second part will make our new `picPick` component declared in `media` module by importing it in the module file and appending it to `declarations` array of this module.

[image: working tree]

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain more to how this answers the question?

Comment: Thank you for your note, I edited my answer as I'm a future reader @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 10):

First generate module:

```
ng g m moduleName --routing
```

This will create a moduleName folder then Navigate to module folder

```
cd moduleName
```

And after that generate component:

```
ng g c componentName --module=moduleName.module.ts --flat
```

Use --flat for not creating child folder inside module folder

Answer (score 8):

```
ng g c componentName --module=path-to-your-module-from-src-folder
```

example:

```
ng g c testComponent --module=/src/app/home/test-component/test-component.module
```

Answer (score 7):

A common pattern is to create a feature with a route, a lazy loaded module, and a component.

Route: `myapp.com/feature`

*app-routing.module.ts*

```
{ path: 'feature', loadChildren: () => import('./my-feature/my-feature.module').then(m => m.MyFeatureModule) },
```

File structure:

```
app   
└───my-feature
│   │   my-feature-routing.module.ts
│   │   my-feature.component.html
│   │   my-feature.component.css
│   │   my-feature.component.spec.ts
│   │   my-feature.component.ts
│   │   my-feature.module.ts
```

This can all be done in the cli with:

```
ng generate module my-feature --module app.module --route feature
```

Or shorter

```
ng g m my-feature --module app.module --route feature
```

Or if you leave out the name the cli will prompt you for it. Very useful when you need to create several features

```
ng g m --module app.module --route feature
```

Answer (score 7):

I have used the following command in the angular CLI version 8.3, and it worked by generating a specific component declared in a specific module.

1. move to the specific folder were we need the component to be generated

   `cd <component-path>`
2. Call the below generate command

   `ng g c <component-name> --module=<module-name>`

### Example

```
 `ng g c login --module= app`
```

Answer (score 6):

> **TL;DR** 
> Try this. Specify the module name by module's file name(excluding the .ts extension)
>
> ```
> ng g c components/path-to-a-folder/component-name --module=app.module
> ```

**Notes:**

- `ng g c` is short for `ng generate component`
- If you want the component to be added in a different module, let's say in file
  `collection.module.ts` then use `--module=collection.module`
  instead of `--module=app.module` & you should be good to go.

Answer (score 4):

Go to module level/we can also be in the root level and type below commands

```
ng g component "path to your component"/NEW_COMPONENT_NAME -m "MODULE_NAME"
```

Example :

```
ng g component common/signup/payment-processing/OnlinePayment -m pre-login.module
```

Answer (score 4):

Read the description of `--route` https://angular.io/cli/generate#module-command,

To archive such, you must add the route of that **component-module** to somewhere and specify the route name.

```
   ng generate module component-name --module=any-parent-module --route=route-path
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is what brought you guys here, but I wanted to create a folder with a module, routing and component files. I wanted the component to be declared to the module I created.

For this I found this command to be really helpful.

`ng g m path/to/folder/component --routing && ng g c path/to/folder/component`

This should create a folder with 6 files.

```
CREATE path/to/folder/component/component-routing.module.ts (253 bytes)
CREATE path/to/folder/component/component.module.ts (297 bytes)
CREATE path/to/folder/component/component.component.html (26 bytes)
CREATE path/to/folder/component/component.component.spec.ts (655 bytes)
CREATE path/to/folder/component/component.component.ts (295 bytes)
CREATE path/to/folder/component/component.component.scss (0 bytes)
UPDATE path/to/folder/component/component.module.ts (379 bytes)
```

You can remove --routing if you don't want routing.

Answer (score 3):

1.- Create your feature module as usual.

```
ng generate module dirlevel1/module-name
```

2.- You can specify the **ROOT PATH** of your project in **--module** ( only in --module, **(/)** root points to your **PROJECT ROOT** and  **IS NOT THE SYSTEM ROOT!!!**)

```
ng generate component dirlevel1/component-name --module /src/app/dirlevel1/module-name.module.ts
```

Real Example:

```
ng generate module stripe/payment-methods-list
```

```
ng generate component stripe/payment-methods-list --module=/src/app/stripe/payment-methods-list/payment-methods-list.module.ts
```

Output:

```
CREATE src/app/stripe/payment-methods-list/payment-methods-list.component.scss (0 bytes)
CREATE src/app/stripe/payment-methods-list/payment-methods-list.component.html (39 bytes)
CREATE src/app/stripe/payment-methods-list/payment-methods-list.component.spec.ts (768 bytes)
CREATE src/app/stripe/payment-methods-list/payment-methods-list.component.ts (322 bytes)
UPDATE src/app/stripe/payment-methods-list/payment-methods-list.module.ts (311 bytes)
[OK] Generated component!
```

Tested with Angular CLI: 9.1.4

Answer (score 3):

If you need to create **component and module at the same time** you can use command

```
ng g m components/my-control && ng g c $_
```

This will create a module and component in the same directory and component will be added to the closes module by default.

The `$_` means the last argument passed to previous command and in this case its the name used for component and module

Answer (score 3):

ng g c moduleFolderName/componentName --module=moduleName

create a header component in shared module then

```
ng g c shared/header --module=shared
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this simple command:

```
ng g c users/userlist
```

`users`: Your module name.

`userlist`: Your component name.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple apps declared in .angular-cli.json ( e.g. in case working on feature module)

```
"apps": [{
    "name": "app-name",
    "root": "lib",
    "appRoot": ""
}, {...} ]
```

You can :

```
ng g c my-comp -a app-name
```

-a stands for --app (name)

Answer (score 2):

According to Angular docs the way to create a component for specific module is,

```
ng g component <directory name>/<component name>
```

"directory name" = where the CLI generated the feature module

Example :-

```
ng generate component customer-dashboard/CustomerDashboard
```

This generates a folder for the new component within the customer-dashboard folder and updates the feature module with the CustomerDashboardComponent

Answer (score 2):

First run `ng g module newModule`
. Then run `ng g component newModule/newModule --flat`

Answer (score 2):

I created component based child module with specific Root Folder

That cli command below i specified,please check out

```
ng g c Repair/RepairHome -m Repair/repair.module
```

**Repair** is Root Folder of our child module

> -m is --module
>
> c for compount
>
> g for generate

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue today while scaffolding an Angular 9 application. I got the "module does not exist error" whenever I added the `.module.ts` or `.module` to the module name.  The cli only needs the name of the module with no extension.  Assuming I had a module name: `brands.module.ts`, the command I used was

```
ng g c path/to/my/components/brands-component -m brands --dry-run
```

remove the `--dry-run` once you've confirmed the file structure is correct.

Answer (score 2):

---

### Make a module, service and component in particular module

```
Basic:

    ng g module chat     
    ng g service chat/chat -m chat
    ng g component chat/chat-dialog -m chat

    In chat.module.ts:
        exports: [ChatDialogComponent],
        providers: [ChatService]

    In app.module.ts:

        imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            ChatModule
        ]

    Now in app.component.html:
        <chat-dialog></chat-dialog>


LAZY LOADING:
    ng g module pages --module app.module --route pages

        CREATE src/app/pages/pages-routing.module.ts (340 bytes)
        CREATE src/app/pages/pages.module.ts (342 bytes)
        CREATE src/app/pages/pages.component.css (0 bytes)
        CREATE src/app/pages/pages.component.html (20 bytes)
        CREATE src/app/pages/pages.component.spec.ts (621 bytes)
        CREATE src/app/pages/pages.component.ts (271 bytes)
        UPDATE src/app/app-routing.module.ts (8611 bytes)       

    ng g module pages/forms --module pages/pages.module --route forms

        CREATE src/app/forms/forms-routing.module.ts (340 bytes)
        CREATE src/app/forms/forms.module.ts (342 bytes)
        CREATE src/app/forms/forms.component.css (0 bytes)
        CREATE src/app/forms/forms.component.html (20 bytes)
        CREATE src/app/forms/forms.component.spec.ts (621 bytes)
        CREATE src/app/forms/forms.component.ts (271 bytes)
        UPDATE src/app/pages/pages-routing.module.ts (437 bytes)
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you have to create a new module using the following command:

```
ng g module newModule
```

Then, you have to go inside that directory using the following command:

```
cd command  
cd newModule
```

And, now you can go ahead using the following command:

```
ng g component newComponent
```

and this component will be created in that module.

Answer (score 2):

If you already created your component without point to a module you can easily add it directly to your app module by adding it to declarations

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [

    FileManagerDetailsComponent <---this is ur page component
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

- `ng g c shared/components/info-card --module=/src/app/shared/shared.module.ts`

Notes:

1. `ng g c` is equivalent to `ng generate component`
2. `shared/components/info-card` is inside my project's `src/app`
   directory & this is how I would use it to create a component with the
   name InfoCardComponent inside the shared/components directory
   (without specifying src/app).
3. BUT, to add this newly created component to a specific module, you
   need to include /src/app in the path to the module because otherwise
   it would say that the module doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Angular 13+ cli

I have multiple modules under modules folder

```
ng g c components/shared/newlayout -m modules/Shared
```

Answer (score 1):

**Add a component to the Angular 4 app using Angular CLI**

To add a new Angular 4 component to the app, use command `ng g component componentName`. After execution of this command, Angular CLI adds a folder `component-name` under `src\app`. Also, the references of the same is added to `src\app\app.module.ts` file automatically.

A component shall have a `@Component` decorator function followed by a `class` which needs to be `export`ed. The `@Component` decorator function accepts meta data.

**Add a component to specific folder of the Angular 4 app using Angular CLI**

To add a new component to a specific folder use the command `ng g component folderName/componentName`

Answer (score 1):

I am having the similar issues with multiple modules in application. A component can be created to any module so before creating a component we have to specify the name of the particular module.

```
'ng generate component newCompName --module= specify name of module'
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this particular command for generating components inside a module.

```
ng g c <module-directory-name>/<component-name>
```

This command will generate component local to the module.
or You can change directory first by typing.

```
cd <module-directory-name>
```

and then create component.

```
ng g c <component-name>
```

Note: code enclosed in <> represent user specific names.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can generate a `Module` using `ng generate module <module name>`.
2. Then use this command to generate a component related to that module, `ng generate component <component name> --module=<module name>`