# Ionic 4 and Angular 7/8 CLI command to generate a component with specific module

Tags: angular-cli

I have an Ionic4/Angular 7/8 app. I want to create a component and have it auto configured in a specific module using the Angular CLI 7.3.9 and 8.1.3, but keep getting the error "File ... does not exist."

None of the answers in this post works either.
[Create component to specific module with Angular-CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40649799/create-component-to-specific-module-with-angular-cli)

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**

1. Create module: `ng g module pets`

This created a file named pets.module.ts in the [my_project_dir]/src/app/pets directory.

2. Generate a component and add to specified module using CLI 7.3.9 or 8.1.3

```
ng g component pets/cat --module=pets.module.ts
ng g component pets/cat --module=pets/pets.module.ts
```

Executing the either the above command from my project directory or from the [my_project_dir]/src/app directory triggered this error message **File pets/pets.module.ts does not exist.**

Issuing this command `ng g component pets/cat -m pets.module.ts` in 7.3.9 created the component cat, but neither pets.module.ts or app.module.ts was updated.

Issuing the command `ng g component pets/cat -m pets.module.ts` in 8.1.3 caused this error message: **Unknown option: '-m'**

As a workaround, I could update the module.ts file manually but would like to know the solution for future reference.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

**Updated 10/16/2019 6:30pm**

It works if the Angular app is created using `ng new app-name` command, but does **NOT** if the app is generated via the `ionic start app-name blank --type=angular` command although the project structure is very similar between the two apps.

Comment: `ng g c pets/cat`

Comment: That just creates the component within the pets directory without updating the module.  I wanted the component automatically configured in the module.

Comment: No, it does update the module too.

Comment: Did you verify?  If so, what version of Angular CLI did you use?  I don't think it makes a difference, but my Ionic/Angular project was created using this Ionic v4 command: `ionic start my-app blank --type=angular`

Comment: Yes, I did verify. It does that since forever, but I verified with 8.1.3. Did **you** verify?

Comment: Yes.  I created a fresh Angular app via the `ng new ...` command and it worked.  There could be a bug with Ionic 4 or some setting in my Ionic 4/Angular 7 app that prevents the `ng g component pets/cat` from updating the module.

Comment: I have the exact same problem in an ionic5/Angular11 project... None of the answers provided here has worked. If starting a project with `ionic start` is causing it, then i guess the `--module` option is broken in ionic?

Answer (score 1):

```
ng new petstore --skip-install
cd petstore
ng g module pets
ng g component pets/cat -m pets
```

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CatComponent } from './cat/cat.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [CatComponent], // <- note this
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class PetsModule { }
```

```
ng version

Angular CLI: 8.3.10
Node: 10.15.3
OS: linux x64
Angular: 8.2.11
```

I can't reproduce ng-cli v8.1.3 since I don't have that installed.
"works for me".
Try issuing the exact same commands as I did. aka just naming the module `pets` not `pets.module.ts` or other

```
tree src/app 
src/app
├── app.component.css
├── app.component.html
├── app.component.spec.ts
├── app.component.ts
├── app.module.ts
└── pets
    ├── cat
    │   ├── cat.component.css
    │   ├── cat.component.html
    │   ├── cat.component.spec.ts
    │   └── cat.component.ts
    └── pets.module.ts

2 directories, 10 files
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to specify the module if you already created the module.

```
ng g m pets
```

this should generate a folder called pets with a file called pets.module.ts

then when you run

```
ng g c pets/cat
```

It should generate a cat.component.ts inside pets/cat folder.

I'd recommend to change a little bit your structure to something like:

```
app/
  modules/
    pets/
      components/
        cat/
          cat.component.[ts, html, scss, spec.ts]
      pets.module.ts
      pets.component.[ts, html, scss, spec.ts]
app.component.ts
app.component.html
app.module.ts
```

So you do: `ng g m modules/pets` and then `ng g c modules/pets/components` or using the --module(-m) flag

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem and I fixed it using below command.

```
ng g component pets/cat --module=/src/app/pets/pets.module.ts --export=true
```

or

```
ionic g component pets/cat --module=/src/app/pets/pets.module.ts --export=true
```

Answer (score 0):

**Nirmal**'s answer should be the accepted one, confirmed with the latest ionic 5 + angular 10

> I also have the same problem and I fixed it using below command.

```
ng g component pets/cat --module=/src/app/pets/pets.module.ts --export=true
```

> or

```
ionic g component pets/cat --module=/src/app/pets/pets.module.ts --export=true
```