# How to create module and component with single command using angular cli and create component for existing module?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

The below comment is not working for me to create a component in the existing module

**ng g c component -m=app.module.ts**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40649799/create-component-to-specific-module-with-angular-cli

Comment: as of right now not possible , you need to use atleast 2 command as given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40649799/create-component-to-specific-module-with-angular-cli

Answer (score 0):

You can do by angular cli cmd:

```
ng g m /pages/home-page && ng g c /pages/home-page
```

or you  can create module with routing as you prefered:

```
ng g m /pages/home-page--routing=true && ng g c /pages/home-page
```